# What game is the guard playing in Battlefield Hardline?

Tags: game-identification, battlefield-hardline

During one of the missions in Battlefield Hardline, you can see this guard playing a video game while he's completely oblivious to everything else around him.
What game is he playing?

[image: Guard playing a game]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is Dead Space 2.  [See this video](http://www.ign.com/videos/2015/03/19/battlefield-hardline-dead-space-easter-egg) and it shows that same scene around the 25 second mark.  The [IGN page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-hardline/Easter_Eggs) for the easter eggs in the game indicate that it is Dead Space 2.  I can also tell that is Dead Space 2 because of the blue lines going down the characters back as shown in this picture (which indicates your health in the game):

[image: dead space]

Other things that give it away is the work bench as shown in the video I linked, and the weapon he is using (it looks like the [infamous Plasma Cutter](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Plasma_Cutter)).

Additional information: both of these games are published by Electronic Arts, and share the same developer (Visceral Games).